# Listing Possible Location From Google Map in Iphone

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to build an app where the user's current location will be displayed. I have done this by using reverse geocoding and I am getting the right address of the user current location. But now I want to get all the possible location that will match against the location entered by the user in the search box. Also I just want to show the location name in the table view but not on the map. Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the related code and details about the problem you are having? Are you looking for just addresses?

Comment: Why not just use the Google Places API and/or it's autocomplete feature: http://goo.gl/9DFXs